# Can anyone help me understand this simple sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I cant not get the meaning of this sentence (the one in bold). Can you please help? Thank you!

The shipping industry is taking steps to reduce its environmental impact and the international maritime organization is committed to at least halving carbon dioxide emissions by 2020.
Shipping is hard to regulate however, **given how mobile ship registration and oversight can be.**

Comment: Can you please review your post? cant not is not right. given that= because of how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"..given how [x] can be.." means *considering the implications of [x]*.

Evidently, registering and keeping oversight of ships which are moving around (mobile) makes shipping regulation difficult.